# Bitbucket git issue on Linux

Tags: linux, git, terminal, bitbucket

I am very new to bitbucket and linux. I am trying to upload files from my local to bitbucket. I tried the following command:

```
git commit -m 'commit to master'
git push -u origin 'master'
```

Then I got an error like

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository. 
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Then I tried

```
git remote add origin ssh://mjsofttechindia@bitbucket.org:mjsofttechindia/project.git
git push origin master
```

Then I got an error like

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 
>   bitbucket.org:yourname: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Please help.  I don't know if this is correct or not.  Please help me.

Comment: You have a colon `:` after `bitbucket.org`, it should be a forward slash `/`

Comment: It's either `mjsofttechindia@bitbucket.org:mjsofttechindia/project.git` or `ssh://mjsofttechindia@bitbucket.org/mjsofttechindia/project.git`

Answer (score 2):

Change remote url to

`ssh://mjsofttechindia@bitbucket.org/mjsofttechindia/project.git`

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://mjsofttechindia@bitbucket.org/mjsofttechindia/project.git
```

Then you have to configure your name and email address (the one that you created your Bitbucket account with) in your local repository

```
git config user.name "Your Name"

git config user.email "you@email.com"
```

Then do a push again

```
git push -u origin master
```